# How to get permission without getting exception?

Tags: android, camera, android-permissions

I am writing app for android.And When I open my app get exception message firstly . İt is different thing for me because I made many apps and there is no such thing.Now I am triying to get permission from user without exception.When I cliked to run button on Android Studio. Emulator gives me error message with request permission box. I want to take only request permission from user without getting exception message after all that I go to my activity.By the way I am so beginner this topic. How can I do that ?

My xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

My code :

```
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: No. I tried first one.(checkSelfPermission ) And It is useless. I mension like to native app. İt is when you bought a new mobile phone. Fİrstly request after enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        int requestCode = 100;

        // Check if permission is already granted. If Granted you need not ask
        if (ContextCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != (int)PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != (int)PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Check if user has opted "Never show again"
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            // Application has the requested permission.
            // Write your further logic, what's next after permission is granted
        }
```

Comment: When I pasted your code to my oncreate void then I change getActivity() to this. Android studio gives me .Error message "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to 'int' 'boolean'.

Comment: Edited my answer, I've updated the condition. Please check

Comment: Still There are red color on getActivity() codes.( all)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You have to cast the Permission to int. I've updated my answer please check.